# исправить повреждение

Tags: mysql

Как исправить поврежденную конфигурацию сервера в `MySQL`?
[Исправляем поврежденные MySQL-таблицы с myisamchk](https://habrahabr.ru/company/kingservers/blog/257291/). Учусь вот на таком примере...
Какие есть утилиты, помимо такой инструкции?

Comment: @vicpanfilov пишет: *исправить поврежденную конфигурацию MySQL — даже затрудняю дать совет...судя по вашей ссылке у вас повреждена сама таблица, я бы поискал похожий софт, должна быть триал версия, может поможет https://www.fixtoolbox.com/ru/repairtoolformysql.html может, кто из знатоков и даст дельный совет, но не я увы*

Comment: Уже проходили "подобное" на sources.ru. На одной учетной записи задается вопрос, на второй учетной записи - ссылка на свое поделие. Вроде и не спам - ответ же! Только у одного и второго, якобы, участника это первое сообщение. Неужели в ruSO этого горе-SEO доселе не было?